# Source control of posts.

Tags: feature-request, editing, edit-history

I could not find this issue anywhere in Meta, so here it comes..

Some users has the privilege to correct or change posts. This is all good, but there is a big problem here - there should be a source control (like CVS, Source Safe etc) so that two users don't change the same post at the same time (I have seen this more than once).

Comment: You mean an ["edit lock"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Edit_lock)?

Comment: @J.M.: Right, please up-vote if you agree.

Comment: Related meta.SO feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/preventing-conflicting-simultaneous-edits

Comment: @KennyTM♦: Yes, that is related.